# Замена элементов массива массивом

Tags: python, массивы

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать задачу: есть двумерный массив вида:

```
   a = array([[1, 1], [1, -1]])
```

нужно заменить каждую единичку, например другим массивом, если это 1, то

```
   zam1 = array([[1, 1], [1, -1]])
```

а если это -1, то

```
 zam2 = array([[0, 0], [0, -1]])
```

Желательно это сделать стандартными средствами (я, например, при помощи numpy аналогичное сделал). Подскажите, как реализовать, заранее спасибо!

Comment:  1. Не массив , а список.
 2. Нужно заменить элемент массив одним массивом или двумя
 3. Откуда будут браться эти данные

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если проблема в том, что нужно пройти многомерный массив рекурсивно, то можно сделать так:

```
def repl(x):
   if x ==  1: return [[1, 1], [1, -1]]
   if x == -1: return [[0, 0], [0, -1]]
   return map(repl, x) if hasattr(x, '__iter__') else x

repl([[1, 1], [1, -1]]) # [[[[1, 1], [1, -1]], [[1, 1], [1, -1]]], [[[1, 1], [1, -1]], [[0, 0], [0, -1]]]]
```

Comment: Впринципе всё понятно, большое спасибо за все ответы!

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [-1,1,0,-1,1]
i = 0
while i < len(a):
    if a[i] == 1:
        a[i] = Нужный текст
    elif a[i] == -1:
        a[i] = Другой текст
```

Comment: danial72, я не знаю, почему в python-e, набор однотипных, индексированных данных называется списком, поэтому называю такое чудо по привычке массивом=)
Сейчас посмотрю Ваш пример.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы дополнила решение словарем, допустим мы потом захотим 20 заменять на [[0,1], [1,0]] или еще как-то изменить ключи/значения

```
a = [[1, 1], [1, -1]]

my_dict = {
  1: [[1, 1], [1, -1]],
  -1: [[0, 0], [0, -1]]
}

for out_i, item in enumerate(a):
  for inner_i, sub_item in enumerate(item):
    if sub_item in my_dict:
      a[out_i][inner_i] = my_dict[sub_item]

print(a)
```

Или если взять за основу решение выше:

```
def repl(x):
  if not hasattr(x, '__iter__') and x in my_dict: return my_dict[x]
  return list(map(repl, x)) if hasattr(x, '__iter__') else x


print(list(repl([[1, 1], [1, -1]])))
```